# How to say "give me some time" in a certain context

Tags: word-requests

How does one say "give me time" in the context of "please give me some time to answer you love confession". Possible candidates are:

告白を答えるように時間かかる - But it seems awfully rude and business formal to use 時間かかる

告白を答えるように時間をください - Sounds slightly better but I get the feeling it's still not quite right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

少し時間をください is natural and you can also say 少し考えさせてください.

告白を答えるよう is unnatural. 返事する is natural in this situation, so 返事するまで少し時間をください or just 少し考えさせてください is natural.